# Find By Title In JPA+THYMELEAF

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a list of multiple rows in my database but my query returns only 1 row instead of more rows.

I want to find my books by title, but for example when I have more than 1 book with the same word in its title, I want to show both books, but the query does not return it.

**HTML Page**

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/searchbook(param=${book?.getBookTitle()})}" th:object="${book}" >        
    <label for="title">Find Book by Title</label>
    <input type="text" id="title" name="title" th:value="${book?.getBookTitle()}" placeholder="Book Title"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Search"/>

    <table id="table1">

          <tr>
             <th>ID</th>
             <th>Title</th>
             <th>Author</th>
             <th>Copies</th>
          </tr>

          <tr th:each="re:${book}" id="tr1">
               <td th:text="${book?.getId()}">id</td>
               <td th:text="${book?.getBookTitle()}" id="ln">title</td>
               <td th:text="${book?.getBookAuthor()}">author</td>
               <td th:text="${book.getBookCopies()}">copies</td>
           </tr>
    </table>

         <!--    <a th:href="@{/update(idNumber=${reader?.idNumber},firstname=${reader?.firstname})}" th:field="*{firstname}">Update</a>
             <a th:href="@{/delete(idNumber=${reader?.idNumber})}" th:value="${reader?.idNumber}">Delete</a>
        -->
</form>
```

**BookController**

```
@GetMapping({"/searchbook","/searchbook{title}"})
public String searchBookByTitle(@RequestParam("title") Optional<String> title, Model model){

    if(title.isPresent()) {
         List<Book> bookList = bookService.findBookByTitle(title.get());
         for(Book book1:bookList) {
              model.addAttribute("book", book1);
         }
         return "book/searchbook";
    }
    else
    {
         return "book/searchbook";
    }
}
```

**Book Repository**

```
@Repository
public interface BookRepository extends CrudRepository<Book,Long> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM BOOK where book_title like %:bookTitle%",nativeQuery = true)
    List<Book> findBooksByBookTitle(String bookTitle);
}
```

**BookServiceImpl**

```
@Override
public List<Book> findBookByTitle(String title) {
    List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();
    bookRepository.findBooksByBookTitle(title)
                  .forEach(books::add);
    for(Book book:books)
                System.out.println(book);
    return books;
}
```

**Console Log**

```
2019-10-13 20:50:44.879 DEBUG 16322 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to public java.lang.String vleunti.springbootframework.libraryapp.controllers.BookController.searchBookByTitle(java.util.Optional<java.lang.String>,org.springframework.ui.Model)
    Optional[Amintiri]
    2019-10-13 20:50:44.880 DEBUG 16322 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] org.hibernate.SQL                        : SELECT * FROM BOOK where book_title like ?
    Book{id=1, bookTitle='Amintiri din Copilarie', bookAuthor='Ion Creanga', bookCopies=3}
    Book{id=2, bookTitle='Amintiri de Acasa', bookAuthor='Victor Leunti', bookCopies=1}
    Book{id=3, bookTitle='Amintiri de altadata', bookAuthor='Vasea Mure', bookCopies=1}
```

In the console, I see 3 rows with the searched word, but on my webpage I see only 1 row. I suppose there is something wrong with my Controller, with `model.addAttribute`...

What could be the reason?

Comment: You're only storing **one** book in the model (or rather, you're storing all of them, but the last one overwrites the previous one). If you want to display a list of books, then the model must contain... a list of books: `model.addAttribute("books", bookList);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I've modified the controller:

   ```
   @GetMapping({"/searchbook","/searchbook{title}"})
   public String searchBookByTitle(@ModelAttribute("title") @RequestParam("title") Optional<String> title, Model model,Book book){
       System.out.println(title);

       if(title.isPresent()) {
           List<Book> bookList = bookService.findBookByTitle(title.get());
           model.addAttribute("book",book);
           model.addAttribute("book2", bookList);
           return "book/searchbook";
       }
       else
       {
           return "book/searchbook";}
   }
   ```

And thymeleaf

```
2. Thymeleaf code

<form action="#" th:action="@{/searchbook(param=${book?.getBookTitle()})}" th:object="${book}" >

    <label for="title">Find Book by Title</label>
    <input type="text" id="title" name="title" th:value="${book?.getBookTitle()}" placeholder="Book Title"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Search"/>

    <table id="table1" th:object="${book2}">
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Author</th>
            <th>Copies</th>
        </tr>
        <tr th:each="carte, state :${book2}" id="tr1"
                th:classappend="${state.odd}?'odd-row':'even-row'">
            <td th:text="${state.count}">id</td>
            <td th:text="${carte.bookTitle}">title</td>
            <td th:text="${carte.bookAuthor}">author</td>
            <td th:text="${carte.bookCopies}">copies</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
 <!--    <a th:href="@{/update(idNumber=${reader?.idNumber},firstname=${reader?.firstname})}" th:field="*{firstname}">Update</a>
     <a th:href="@{/delete(idNumber=${reader?.idNumber})}" th:value="${reader?.idNumber}">Delete</a>
-->
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Watch out with the `th:action` you can't just put `(parm=$..)` there to check for parameters you must define it first. It would look like:

```html
<form action="#" th:action="@{/searchbook{param}(param=${BookTitle})}" th:object="${book}" >

    <label for="BookTitle">Find Book by Title</label>
    <input type="text" id="BookTitle" name="BookTitle" th:value="${BookTitle}" placeholder="Book Title"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Search"/>

    <table id="table1" th:object="${book2}">
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Author</th>
            <th>Copies</th>
        </tr>
        <tr th:each="carte, state :${book2}" id="tr1"
                th:classappend="${state.odd}?'odd-row':'even-row'">
            <td th:text="${state.count}">id</td>
            <td th:text="${carte.bookTitle}">title</td>
            <td th:text="${carte.bookAuthor}">author</td>
            <td th:text="${carte.bookCopies}">copies</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
 <!--    <a th:href="@{/update(idNumber=${reader?.idNumber},firstname=${reader?.firstname})}" th:field="*{firstname}">Update</a>
     <a th:href="@{/delete(idNumber=${reader?.idNumber})}" th:value="${reader?.idNumber}">Delete</a>
-->
</form>
```